# Error while using Stored Procedure with dynamic sql in SSIS OLE-DB source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, dynamic-sql, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package which uses a stored procedure with dynamic SQL as OLEDB source. When I execute the package, I get this error

> Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement
>   'exec sp_executesql @sqlStr' in procedure 's_offc_cap_st_rpt_efile' 
>   contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to
>   explicitly describe the result set.".

The `Oledb source` configuration looks like this:

[image]

What is the reason for this error? Could someone help me find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you try using the WITH RESULT SETS clause like the error message says?

Comment: i tried to give it inside stored proc...doesn't worked out

Comment: Then you did it wrong.   Please post your attempt so we can help debug it.  You don't use it in the stored proc, but in the call.   See here:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/28328734/1507566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Package not wanting to fetch metadata of temporary table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346484/ssis-package-not-wanting-to-fetch-metadata-of-temporary-table)

Comment: the sp output record is having more than 100 columns...thats why tried inside the stored proc

Comment: Sorry it's going to be painful, but that's the way it works.   Do it correctly and it will work.

Comment: ok let me give a try

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is always required select column list to create the meta data so that column names in SSIS can be mapped to appropriate output\destination.

Here you are using dynamic sql which will compile and run at run time it self. If you want to remove this error. I would recommend create table variable and get output of your dynamic sql into this table variable and write select * from @tablevaribale. So that procedure will return the column list to the ssis.

Comment: the dynamic sql is created inside a stored procedure..if i create a table variable inside the stored procedure will it work

Comment: @bmsqldev yes once you create table variable and dump output of dynamic sql and then write select statement on that table variable that will work. Please let me know in case you find still issue