# How to fix 'metadata could not be determined error in SSIS OLEDBCOMMAND'

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, oledbcommand

I have an ssis package. In one data flow task, i am using oledbcommand task to run Stored procedure

```
exec adminstroedproc ? ? ?
```

we have recently upgrade the sql server to 2017. Earlier it uses sql server 2008.

Earlier it was working fine in OLEDBCOMMAND. After up-gradation it throws an error.
When i executing this stored procedure directly in SSMS it's running good... But when i calling this stored procedure from OLEDBCOMMAND Task getting error message saying that

> The metadata could not be determined because select statement in procedure uses a temp table.
>
> unable to retrieve destination column descriptions from the parameters of the sql command.

I tried with global temp table and using with result sets as well. But still getting error. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Using "with result sets" should prevent it. Could you post your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Package not wanting to fetch metadata of temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346484/ssis-package-not-wanting-to-fetch-metadata-of-temporary-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fully qualified procedure name: `[database].[schema].[procedure]` example `master.dbo.adminstroedproc`

Also check that the `TargetServerVersion` is set to `SQL Server 2017`

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)